# Permgen out of memory exception not shown?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, permgen

I have a java swing application, that I am trying to monitor with jvisualvm.
When I monitor the application and I so some tests with jvisualvm active I got the permgen exception.
If I just run it doing the same exact things like when i monitor it with jvisualvm all seems fine.

I used jmap -permstat or -heap and i see the permgen space that decrease when it's near it's limit.

Maybe when I am not running jvisualvm the exception is thrown but it's not shown in eclipse console? 
I understand it's very difficult to get an idea with this little informations, but some advices to why I got this strange behaviour?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Which version of java is this and what is exact error/exception you are getting ?

Comment: @Vipin unfortunately it's an old 1.6.0_35, the error I am getting is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Comment: Did you try increasing permgen space ?

Comment: Yes I tried, same, with jvisualvm on it consume all the permgen space and i got the exception, without it the tests run fine.

Comment: Profiling tools like jvisualvm adds some memory overhead probably that is causing problem in your case. But that memory overhead is really low, try to get heapdump when there is out of memory error and analyse that.

Comment: Get the heap dump use -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError as jvm argument to get it and then analyze it. for analysis see my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888121/how-to-identify-holder-of-reference-to-object-in-java-memory-analyzer-using-heap/24895215#24895215)